# Make calendar scrollable in a list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a date picker. Which is easy to access from mobile device. I am using default calendar now. Now, days are showing in a header. But, I want to show day and date side by side vertically. Example,

```
    Sun 1
    Mon 2
    Tues 3 and so on
```

Please check the code below.

```js
 var datePicker = $(".calendar").datepicker({});
```

```css
.datepicker {
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" style="height: 400px; overflow: scroll">
    <div style="height:300px"></div>
    <div>Choose Date:
        <input class="calendar" />
    </div>
    <div style="height:300px"></div>
</div>
```

It will be great if you use http://jsfiddle.net/ while giving answer.

Comment: Please fix the code in your question to load the JS dependencies (jquery and the calendar plugin).